# Disable program from starting at boot on cent6, mounted filesystem

Tags: centos, boot, sysvinit, rc.d

I am mounting a filesystem with guestfish. It is a Cent6 machine. I want to be sure that it is not going to start http on boot. I can't `chmod -x /etc/rc.d/init.d/http`, so I've opted to:
`mv /etc/rc.d/init.d/http /tmp/`.

As this is a mounted filesystem in guestfish, I can't issue a chkconfig off on this service. Is the above adequate in ensuring the program won't start on boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are correct. 
If the startup files (http in your case) are not in /etc/rc.d/init.d it shouldn't start. 
There can be scripts that start apps outside of systemv but normally an app would start from that folder using systemv services.